# IDLE Debugger cannot process input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, python-idle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAxnL.jpg

I'm learning how to use the debugger and it locks up whenever I get to the input() line. I've tried typing in my input and hitting enter, nothing happens. When I try to Go or Over it locks up and when I Step it just opens the module window and take me through that only to lock up in there.

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER for anyone stuck on this same issue: The debugger doesn't expect a user response UNTIL the Go, etc. buttons are greyed out. That is your cue to enter a response.